# Select query with having keyword along with inner query gives an error - ORA-00979

Tags: sql, oracle

`loan_transaction` table has records that are inserting like transactions. So there can be positive and negative values in the `amount` column.

Table `loan_transaction` something like bellow

| id | set_off_id | amount | account_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 23 |
| 2 | 1 | -100 | 23 |

Plan to use this query in a pagination search function that was written in Java with JPQL.
Before implementing with JPQL I have to make sure this can be achieved by single query.

Inner query inside the HAVING clause itself returning the desired out-put, but when I merge
outer query, this is not working. Showing error as "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression".

```
SELECT lad.id
FROM account_detail ad
WHERE ad.account_status_code IN ('ASDS')
HAVING (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lto.txn_date)
    FROM loan_transaction lto
    WHERE lto.id IN (
        SELECT lti.set_off_id
        from loan_transaction lti
        WHERE lti.account_id = ad.id
        GROUP BY lt.set_off_id
        HAVING SUM(lt.amount) > 0)
        ) > 6;
```

Could you correct me what I am doing wrong in here ?

I want to retrieve `account_detail` records that contains ASDS as `account_status_code` and
distinct `txn_date` count should be larger than the given value (in this example 6) which having amount greater that 0.

Comment: Change the first `HAVING` to `AND`?

Comment: Can you add some sample data, and also specify the expected result. I.e. a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyword `HAVING` should be followed by an aggregate function. Here it is followed by expression.

Solution is either to incorporate that expression into existing `Where` clause (no 1st `Having` clause at all) or to do aggregation of the selection done by select statement within current `Having` clause.

I just tried to simulate your code (there are some syntax mistakes that raise errors) - and to my own surprise **it works** in 3 different ways (including your own after corrections).

Here are simulations:

```sql
--  First - your way (with corrections)
SELECT ad.ID      -- you have wrong alias here - lad.id -> lad does not exist
FROM 
    (Select 2 "ID", 'ASDS' "ACCOUNT_STATUS_CODE" From Dual) ad  -- acting like your account_detail table
WHERE 
    ad.ACCOUNT_STATUS_CODE = 'ASDS'
HAVING 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lto.TXN_DATE)
        FROM  (
                  Select '2X' "ID", 2 "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('01.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", '2X' "SET_OFF_ID", -12 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All
                  Select '2X' "ID", 2 "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('02.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", '2X' "SET_OFF_ID", 14 "AMOUNT" From Dual
              ) lto  -- acting like your loan_transaction table
        WHERE lto.ID IN   (
                          SELECT lti.SET_OFF_ID
                          FROM  (
                                    Select '2X' "ID", 2 "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('01.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", '2X' "SET_OFF_ID", -12 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All
                                    Select '2X' "ID", 2 "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('02.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", '2X' "SET_OFF_ID", 14 "AMOUNT" From Dual
                                ) lti   -- acting like your loan_transaction table (Again)
                          WHERE lti.ACCOUNT_ID = ad.ID
                          GROUP BY lti.SET_OFF_ID   -- you have lt.set_off_id  --> lt alias does not exist
                          HAVING SUM(lti.AMOUNT) > 0)
    ) > 1;
--  
--  Second - incorporate it into existing Where clause
--  change HAVING with AND
...
WHERE 
    ad.ACCOUNT_STATUS_CODE = 'ASDS'
AND 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lto.TXN_DATE)
        FROM  (
...
--
-- Third - aggregate the selection of query in your HAVING clause
--
...
HAVING 
    Max((
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lto.TXN_DATE)
        FROM  (
                  Select '2X' "ID", 2 "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('01.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", '2X' "SET_OFF_ID", 12 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All
                  Select '2X' "ID", 2 "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('02.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", '2X' "SET_OFF_ID", 12 "AMOUNT" From Dual
              ) lto
        WHERE lto.ID IN   (
                          SELECT lti.SET_OFF_ID
                          FROM  (
                                    Select '2X' "ID", 2 "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('01.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", '2X' "SET_OFF_ID", -12 "AMOUNT" From Dual Union All
                                    Select '2X' "ID", 2 "ACCOUNT_ID", To_Date('02.11.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TXN_DATE", '2X' "SET_OFF_ID", 14 "AMOUNT" From Dual
                                ) lti
                          WHERE lti.ACCOUNT_ID = ad.ID
                          GROUP BY lti.SET_OFF_ID
                          HAVING SUM(lti.AMOUNT) > 0)
    )) > 1;
--
-- Result for each of the above simulations is the same
--
        ID
----------
         2
```

Regards...